# Использование именованных групп в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Есть шаблон с именованными группами захвата и код, который я нарыл https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/:

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?si)p:processName=(?P<DB>[^,]+)(?:r.+?)(Context=(?P<Context>[^,]+))`)
for _, submatches := range re.FindAllStringSubmatchIndex(*Blob, -1) {
    DB, Context := []byte{}, []byte{}
    DB = re.ExpandString(DB, "$DB", *Blob, submatches)
    Context = re.ExpandString(Context, "$Context", *Blob, submatches)
    fmt.Print(string(DB))
}
```

С этим действительно такие сложности в го при работе с именованными группами, или я что-то накостылил?

Comment: Что у вас за проблема? Что не так?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Например, у ОПа один и тот же регексп выполняется три раза вместо одного. Так что проблема реальна.

Comment: @Ainar-G, если вы про FindAllStringSubmatchIndex, то он тут один раз выполняется.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, проблема в громоздкости кода, в перле это на раз два, элегантно

Answer (score 1):

Работа с именованными группами в го действительно проработана не до конца. [Предложение](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24208) об упрощённом интерфейсе было отклонено из-за "взрыва" интерфейса.

---

Изначально я ошибочно посчитал, что программа в ОП проходится три раза, но это не так. Ниже пример моего "улучшенного" решения для истории.

<s>Тем не менее, вашу проблему можно решить одним проходом. Пример:</s>

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?P<first>[a-zA-Z]+) (?P<last>[a-zA-Z]+)")
subs := re.SubexpNames()
matches := re.FindStringSubmatch("Alan Turing")
for i := range matches {
    fmt.Printf("%10q = %q\n", subs[i], matches[i])
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oJAkefhkSNU.

Comment: все равно не удобно, было бы куда удобней если бы SubexpNames возвращал map, тогда обращение было бы как-то так:
matches[sub["имя группы"]]

Comment: Я согласен, но в то же время создателей языка и ст. библиотеки можно понять. Ограничения языка диктуют, что либо у вас 100500 функций, либо у вас слаботипизированные "универсальные" функции. Возможно, в го 2 с этим что-то сделают.